# UnicodeString compatibility issue

Tags: c++, unicode, c++builder, vcl

I am porting an older project from C++ Builder 2009 to XE5. In the old project, the compiler option for Unicode strings was set as "`_TCHAR` maps to: char". This worked fine in the old project.

When porting it, I set the same compiler option in XE5. But I still get compiler errors for code like this:

```
std::string str = String(some_component.Text).t_str();
```

This gives the following errors:

> [bcc32 Warning] file.cpp(89): W8111 Accessing deprecated
>   entity 'UnicodeString::t_str() const'
>
> [bcc32 Error] file.cpp(89): E2285 Could not find a match for
>   'operator string::=(wchar_t *)'

So apparently XE5 has decided that `String::t_str()` should give me a `wchar_t*` rather than a `char*`, even though I have set the compiler option as described above.

How do I solve this?

I am well-aware that C++ Builder has taken the step to use Unicode internally (even in the 2009 version), but this is an old project with 200k LOC. Updating it to Unicode would be a steep task with very low priority.

**EDIT**

I can get it to work by changing the code to

```
std::string str = AnsiString(some_component.Text).c_str();
```

But this means I have to change the code at numerous places. Is there a better way that doesn't involve rewriting code?

Comment: If nothing else comes up you could resort to #define String(a) AnsiString(a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `UnicodeString::t_str()` was first introduced in CB2009, it returned either a `char*` or `wchar_t*` depending on what TCHAR mapped to.  In order to return a `char*`, it ALTERED the internal data of the UnicodeString to make it Ansi (thus breaking the contract that UnicodeString is a Unicode string).  **THIS WAS TEMPORARY** for migration purposes while people were still re-writing their code to support Unicode.  This breakage was acceptable because the RTL had special logic to handle Ansi-encoded UnicodeString (and Unicode-encoded AnsiString) values.  However, this was dangerous code.  After a few versions, when people had adequate time to migrate, this RTL logic was removed and `UnicodeString::t_str()` was locked in to `wchar_t*` only, to match `UnicodeString::c_str()`.  **DO NOT USE `t_str()` anymore!**  That is why it is marked as deprecated now.  If you need to pass a UnicodeString to something that expects Ansi data, converting to an intermediate AnsiString is the correct and safe approach.  That is just the way it is now.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I'll just have to roll with the cast to AnsiString + c_str() and rewrite the code. Still a bit strange that the C++ compiler has an internal `String` type which is now 100% incompatible with the C++ standard strings. Unless C++11 or something remade std::string to work with wchar_t?

Comment: C++Builder's `System::String`, `System::Char`, and `System::PChar` aliases exist for compatibility with Delphi's native `String`, `Char`, and `PChar` types.  In CB2009, they map to `UnicodeString`, `wchar_t`, and `wchar_t*`, respectively. In earlier versions, they mapped to `AnsiString`, `char`, and `char*` instead. They have nothing to do with the C++ STL whatsoever. Different frameworks, different types. The STL `std::string` type still uses `char`. For `wchar_t`, use `std::wstring` instead (C++11 also adds new `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` types).